# kvmatrix inserts [b] in each cell

Tags: diagrams

In the past, I had no problems with code similar to the one below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kvmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{kvmap}
\begin{kvmatrix}{B,A}
1 & \\
& 1\\
\end{kvmatrix}
\end{kvmap}
\end{document}
```

But recently, the same code now shows the text `[b]` added to each cell:

[image: kvmatrix]

What can I do to remove this unwanted `[b]`?  I'm using pdfLaTeX, MiKTeX 2.9, and the May 6, 2020 version of kvmap (0.3.4).

Comment: Try loading package `amsmath`. The package uses `\smash[b]` which is undefined in plain LaTeX.

Comment: @TeXnician, wow, that worked!  Please add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package uses `\smash[b]` within the nodes. This command is defined by `amsmath` and not available in the LaTeX core. Loading `amsmath` will solve it for now but probably this should be reported at https://gitlab.com/benfrank/kvmap.